# How to take values from an array in JOLT, put them into an array of object values

Tags: java, json, jolt

For input

```json
{
  "field1": {
    "array1": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "array2": [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want the output:

```json
{
  "objectArray": [
    {
      "role": "to",
      "id": "a"
    },
    {
      "role": "to",
      "id": "b"
    },
    {
      "role": "to",
      "id": "c"
    },
    {
      "role": "to",
      "id": "d"
    }
  ]
}
```

I currently am trying:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "field1": {
        "array1": {
          "#to": "objectArray[].role",
          "@": "objectArray[].id"
        },
        "array2": {
          "#to": "objectArray[].role",
          "@": "objectArray[].id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

However this seems to separate out the roles and ids into their own separate objects, after the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this two step of **shift** transformation spec.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "o[].id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "objectArray[&1].&",
          "#to": "objectArray[&1].role"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where you got and array for all ids in the first step, and then adding an arbitrarily chose key-value pairs within the second step while renaming the target array

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this achieves what I need. Out of curiosity, if I wanted the output to different roles that I defined in the transform (array1.role = from, array2.role = reply etc), how might I do that?

Comment: you're welcome @Sheen . I didn't understand what you exactly mean. Can you share as an image link here(as comment) as derived from [this site](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/)